# R user-defined function not seeing argument

Tags: r, user-defined-functions

I am trying to make a function in which I have to provide two arguments. For the first argument, I can enter anything, but for the second only the characters 'A' or 'B' are allowed. Then I wish to return both arguments in a list.

```
myFunction <- function(var1, var2){

  if(missing(var1) | var1 == ""){stop("First argument is missing")}
  if(missing(var2) | var2 != "A" | var2 != "B"){stop("Second argument is missing. Accepted values: 'A' or 'B'")}

  myList <- list("out1" = var1, "out2"=var2)
  return(myList)
}

myFunction("Hello world!", "A")
Error in myFunction("Hello world!", "A") : 
  Second argument is missing. Accepted values: 'A' or 'B'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: you need to have (var2 != "A" & var2 != "B") instead of the or in the var2 condition. (edit: see answer below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's your boolean logic.

```
var2 is missing = F
var2 != 'A' = F
var2 != 'B' = T
```

F or F or T evaluates to T